# Deduplicating CSS rules when using @media queries

Tags: css

I've noticed more and more that my stylesheets generally have repeated rules as a normal selector as well as inside a `@media ... {}` query and generates quite a lot of CSS bloat.

Here's a simple use-case of the problem that I see popping up ad nauseam:

```
.big-red { 
  color:red;
  font-size: 3em;
  ... lots of other stuff 
}
.dynamic-uber-class { 
    color:green;
    font-size:2em;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .dynamic-uber-class { 
    color:red;
    font-size: 3em;
    ... lots of other .big-red duplicated stuff 
  }
}
```

I notice that the problem becomes increasingly problematic when I use mixins in less or scss (because it's really easy to add), but what's really needed is mixins in CSS (for which I won't be holding my breath!). That said, I've noticed [CSS-Properties](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables), with *some* support and [@apply](http://caniuse.com/#search=css-apply) that has no support.

Has anyone stumbled on a **CSS only** way of not having this duplication?

I'm aware that with a bit of Javascript I can simply add/remove classes, but I like my sites working properly with javascript disabled (as much as possible).

**Edit:** 
For those struggling to understand the problem, take a real-world example from bootstrap's grid:

```
.col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-xs-11 {
  width: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-10 {
  width: 83.33333333%;
}
...
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
}
```

If you've ever looked at the generated CSS of bootstrap it is very fat indeed due to the problem.

Comment: I don't really get what you're saying. Are these two classes `.uber-class` and `.dynamic-uber-class` set on the same element?

Comment: wait wait wait, I now noticed the same attributes and same values, are set both on the @media and non media class, this is rather pointless... why are you doing that ?

Comment: @AndreiV The two classes are applied to different elements, of course

Comment: @Stavm The why is rather irrelevant. When writing a CSS library often you need the same features added at different screen widths. Look at any css grid, eg, bootstrap, flexboxgrid, etc, etc.

Comment: If you use a server side language I would have written my own parser for CSS variables and @apply .... and as soon as they work cross browsers simply drop the parser

Comment: Check my answer. There's absolutely no reason to redefine column classes again unless the width has changed. Just because bootstrap is doing that doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: @LGSon Interesting idea, and one definitely worth remembering, but ironcially, am also looking at static html files

Comment: Just because it's on the Internet, it doesn't mean it's true. Bootstrap was always intended for fast prototyping. Then people started pushing sites to production... Anyway, just because Bootstrap does it, does not mean you should also. They may have their reasons. If you're building your own (mini)framework, you're free to optimize.

Comment: @AndreiV I'm using this as an example. I don't use bootstrap myself, because it's too bloated for my liking

Comment: Yeah, I got that :) I was just trying to say that your example is not a "best practice" example and maybe you should consider it as something that one should avoid writing. @l3fty has a great example: write all general rules and bundle them together; then, on breakpoints, set or reset the specific rules.

Comment: @AndreiV, The css is demonstration only. The question is specific. It seems that you and l3fty have gone to great lengths to deliberately take the question on a tangent. I have NOT asked for a specific answer to the example code, I have asked for an answer on a generic problem. Have a look at ANY responsive CSS library and you'll see css property duplication.

Comment: @cmroanirgo I feel you are ignoring the answer. **Don't duplicate already defined styles in your media queries.** Eg. don't put `display: flex;` in your media queries if it's already defined in the original class. As for your grid comment, let's go ahead and look at [Bootstrap's Grid](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/grid.less). Notice how line **14**, **17**, and  **20** are **NOT** the same width.

Comment: Most decent web servers allow one to override its way to deal with both dynamic and static content. I've used IIS for 20 years and have been doing sites working without javascript from the start (with server side client spoofing), so simply parse the html files too and when done, cache the result and you will be able to push them as fast as server does with static files

Comment: @l3fty I'm sorry that you think your answer is correct. I cannot help you read the question properly. Your comments are not constructive and one I have flagged as being downright inappropriate for SO. Please move to the next question. NB: I supplied code from bootstrap's generated css and you ignore that. By comparison, the comments from LGSon are very constructive.

Comment: @LGSon Again, good to think of. I'll probably stick with LESS which (presumably) will roll in the support as it becomes available. In my use-case it is easier to deploy that way.

Comment: @cmroanirgo That's because, again, you have no idea how CSS works and compiles. So now I will stop replying to you because I've already answered your question. I don't care what code you supplied, I've showed you Twitter's repo that contradicts you directly. I've also flagged your original reply to my answer. Good day.

Comment: @l3fty I don't know where your animosity comes from. I'm sorry to have inflamed it. However, look at lines 65, 74, 83 of the LESS file you indicate (& which generates the CSS I quoted) -- and neatly outlines the problem -- because it's the same set of properties being applied/reapplied to the same classes, causing massive bloat.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do about this. CSS has no way of knowing if .big-red and .dynamic-uber-class are meant to represent the same element, or at least the same layout in two different elements depending on the context. If what you're looking for is to deduplicate the *values* themselves, then yes, custom props is the (not robustly supported) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this:

```
.uber-class, .dynamic-uber-class { 
  color:red;
  font-size: 3em;
  ... lots of other duplicated stuff
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .dynamic-uber-class { 
    ... only unique styles
  }
}
```

Comment: ...because the element should not be red on a smaller screen. ;)

Comment: That's a unique style isn't it? So you add that to `.dynamic-uber-class` or visa versa. You just overwrite what you need to if it's not the same.

Comment: I've updated the question to illustrate why this is NOT acceptable, which should have been obvious, or so I thought.

Comment: Tell me why it's not acceptable. To me, this is a question from a non-seasoned CSS dev. It looks like you don't know how CSS works. I would go back and read a little more about it.

Comment: The problem really comes to the fore when using CSS compilation tools such as less-plugin-autoprefix which can turn 'display:flex' into something gargantuan that you really don't want duplicated all over the place.